# Serial Port Counter

Tags: c++, serial-port, counter

I want to connect a simple switch to my computer using a serial port. Whenever the switch gets closed, I want to increment a variable. I am using Visual C++ for the project.

Can anyone show me an approach for this task? I used Google and found examples for reading and writing data over via serial interface but I don't know how to implement a counter.

Comment: What do you mean about not knowing how to implement a counter?  Do you mean the mechanics of initializing and incrementing a variable?

Comment: You can hook the switch to one of the handshake lines, line Ring or CTS.  WaitCommEvent() to see it change.  Beware of the electrical problem you'll have, you have to swing the input line by at least plus/minus 5 volts.  Ask at electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can connect DTR pin of the serial port to pins like DSR or RI via a switch or wire. It's easy to controll the serial port with the serial port class of .NET framework. Code samples can be found on msdn serial port class entry.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this works on a normal serial port, as the serial port in general uses a pulses (several pulses may be the same level for consecutive ones or zeros, but there will at least be pulses for the start/end of a sequence, and typically in the middle). There is a set number of bits in a message, typically 1 start, 8 data and 1 stop bit.

You could do this with a parallel port, or a GPIO pin, if there is such a thing on the system you are working on.

Or you have to implement some more logic than a simple switch, such that the thing sends a sequence of pulses to make up a complete packet, and have a message for "close" and one for "open".

Comment: This is indeed true. The serial port on a PC is controlled by a simple piece of hardware that uses the [RS232](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS232) protocol to send characters between it and the serial port at the other end. The protocol is one of the simplest communication protocols used but it is still not quite as simple as using the parallel port.

Comment: Technically, if we wanted to be a bit tricky, I suppose we could be having a driver that reacts to changes in modem status pins, e.g. CTS and DSR. Wiggling either of those, and we could count them in a driver. But I don't believe this is the solution that the original questioner had in mind.

Comment: Depending on how wide the pulse is, it could be a valid BREAK signal which would be reported to software.

Comment: Yes, there are various ways that it can be connected to a serial port, but I still don't think that's what the original poster had in mind. If I'm wrong, then can @marc please make a comment.